# Controller recebendo parametros null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**//Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditarConfSist(ConfSistMOD confSist)
{
    try
    {
        var repositorio = new ConfSistREP();
        repositorio.EditarConfSist(confSist);


        // gerar o log 
        logar = new LogREP();

        log = new LogMOD();
        log.NomeUsuario = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        log.Login = VariaveisDeSessao.LoginUsuario;
        log.Dt_Log = DateTime.Now;
        log.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
        log.HostName = VariaveisDeSessao.GetHostName(Request.ServerVariables);

        log.Acao = "Apelido " + confSist.dsApelido + " (valor = " + confSist.dsValor + ") foi editado com sucesso.\n"
            + "Detalhes: \n"
            + "Valor = Antes: " + repositorio.dsValorAntigo.dsValor + " \t\tDepois: " + confSist.dsValor + "\n"
            + "dsApelido = Antes: " + repositorio.dsValorAntigo.dsApelido + " \t\tDepois: " + confSist.dsApelido + "\n"
            + "dsDescrição = Antes: " + repositorio.dsValorAntigo.dsDescricao + " \t\tDepois: " + confSist.dsDescricao + "\n";

        //log.IdLogIdTabela = confSist.dsApelido.ToString();
        //string wRetorno = logar.InserirLog(log);

        TempData["Sucesso"] = "Valor editado com Sucesso";

        return RedirectToAction("ConfiguracoesDeSistema");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {// gerar o log
        logar = new LogREP();

        log = new LogMOD();
        log.NomeUsuario = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        log.Login = VariaveisDeSessao.LoginUsuario;
        log.Dt_Log = DateTime.Now;
        log.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
        log.HostName = VariaveisDeSessao.GetHostName(Request.ServerVariables);

        //log.Acao = "Falha ao Editar valor " + confSist.dsApelido + " (valor = " + confSist.dsValor + "). \nMensagem: " + ex.Message + "" + ex.StackTrace;
        //logar.InserirLog(log);

        TempData["Erro"] = "Falha ao editar valor";

        return RedirectToAction("ConfiguracoesDeSistema");
    }
}
```

**// Model**

```
public class ConfSistMOD
{
    //RSS - 15/02/2019

    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apelido")]
    public string dsApelido { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string dsDescricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    public string dsValor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo")]
    public Int16 dsTipo { get; set; }

}
```

**//View**

```
public class ConfSistViewModel
{
   /// model principal
    public ConfSistMOD Config { get; set; }

    public List<ConfSistMOD> ListaConfiguracoes { get; set; }

    //public SelectList Filtros { get; set; }

    public ConfSistViewModel()
    {
        //Inicializar lista
        Config = new ConfSistMOD();
        ConfSistREP confSistCaduREP = new ConfSistREP();
        this.ListaConfiguracoes = confSistCaduREP.CarregarListaDeConfiguracoes();

    }
}
```

**//Repositotio**

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class ConfSistREP
    {
        public ConfSistMOD dsValorAntigo { get; set; }
        public string EditarConfSist(ConfSistMOD confSist)
        {
            using (var conexao = new ConexaoBanco())
            {
                var tbConf = new tbConfiguracoes();
                tbConf.dsApelido = confSist.dsApelido;
                tbConf.dsDescricao = confSist.dsDescricao;
                //tbConf.dsTipo = confSist.dsTipo;
                tbConf.dsValor = confSist.dsValor;

                conexao.tbConfiguracoes.Add(tbConf);
                conexao.SaveChanges();

                return tbConf.dsApelido;
            }
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Apelido</th>
                        <th>Descrição</th>
                        <th>Valor</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var item in Model.ListaConfiguracoes)
                    {
                        using (Html.BeginForm("EditarConfSist", "Lojas", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <tr data-id="@item.ID">

                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBox("model.dsApelido", @item.dsApelido, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBox("model.dsDescricao", @item.dsDescricao, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @if (@item.dsTipo == 1)
                                    {
                                        if (@item.dsValor == "Sim")
                                        {
                                            <select name="model.Dropdownlist">
                                                <option value="False">Não</option>
                                                <option value="True" selected>Sim</option>
                                            </select>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <select name="model.Dropdownlist">
                                                <option value="False" selected>Não</option>
                                                <option value="True" >Sim</option>
                                            </select>

                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        @Html.TextBox("model.dsValor", item.dsValor, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    }
                                </td>


                                @Html.Hidden("model.ID", item.ID)
                               @* @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Opc)*@

                                <td align="center">
                                    <button id="EditarSistConf" type="submit" style="border:none; background-color:transparent"><img src="~/Content/Icones/editar1.png" /></button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Muda o nome dos seus textbox, remova esses `model.`.

Comment: @PedroPaulo resolveu ! Agora está dando outra exception .. Tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? :( 

{"Unable to update the EntitySet 'tbConfiguracoes' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation."}

Comment: Ótimo! Irei postar a resposta para ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema. Quanto ao novo problema, por regras do fórum, você deve abrir uma nova pergunta para esta dúvida, pois é um problema diferente da pergunta original. Abraço!

Comment: Tá bom @PedroPaulo obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está realizando um `POST` no seu formulário da página. Para que o submit envie os dados para o servidor e seu `Controller` reconheça os parâmetros de sua classe `ConfSistMOD`, precisamos nomear os campos dentro do formulário igual ao nomes da sua classe `ConfSistMOD`.

Para resolver o problema, remova os nomes `model.` de todos os seus campos e deixe igual as propriedades de sua classe.

Exemplo:

```
@Html.TextBox("dsDescricao", @item.dsDescricao, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```